# Upload Multiple Images in WEB2PY

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I am new to Web2py and i am get strucked at how to upload multiple images in web2py.Can anyone help me to get out of this?

Comment: Please add some code to demonstrate what you currently have.

Comment: Also, note that there is no built-in functionality for this, so you will need some custom code. The details will depend on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
form_fact.custom.widget.ruta_archivo['_multiple'] = ""
```